# Как запретить выполнение события при нажатии на клавишу, если установлен setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть следующий код:

```js
$(function(){
var i = 0;
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
  if(e.which == 49){
    $(".box").hide();
    i++;
    $(".count").text(i);
    setTimeout(
      function(){
        $(".box").show();
      }, 5000);
  }
});
});
```

```css
.box{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
<span class="count">0</span>
```

При нажатии на клавишу "1" на клавиатуре блок скрывается и запускается setTimeout, после чего блок опять появляется. Так же есть счетчик нажатий, но проблема в том, что можно нажимать клавишу 1 сколько угодно раз когда блок скрыт, как запретить это событие во время setTimeout? Нашел решение через удаление eventListener'a и добавлении его после setTimeout, но код громоздкий, есть более элегантные решения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  var i = 0;
  var timer = null;
  document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (!timer && e.which == 49) {
      $(".box").hide();
      i++;
      $(".count").text(i);
      timer = setTimeout(
        function() {
          $(".box").show();
          timer = null;
        }, 5000);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
<span class="count">0</span>
```